# "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections4/ListValuedMap" on reading excel Apache POI selenium

Tags: java, excel, apache, maven, selenium

I am getting error as below while reading XSSFWorkbook through Apache POI however i am using collection version 4.1 which is latest and also using the latest versions of POI dependencies:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/apache/commons/collections4/ListValuedMap
at ReadXLS.readexcel(ReadXLS.java:27)
at exceldataread.main(exceldataread.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.apache.commons.collections4.ListValuedMap
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

However i am using following maven dependencies-

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>practice</groupId>
<artifactId>Practice_pblm</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<repositories>
<repository>
<id>central</id>
<name>Central Repository</name>
<url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
<layout>default</layout>
<snapshots>
<enabled>false</enabled>
</snapshots>
</repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
<pluginRepository> 
<id>central</id>
<name>Central Repository</name>
<url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
<layout>default</layout>
<snapshots>
<enabled>false</enabled>
</snapshots>
<releases>
<updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
</releases>
</pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<build>
<pluginManagement>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.1</version>
<configuration>
<source>1.8</source>
<target>1.8</target>
</configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</pluginManagement>
</build>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
<version>4.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
<version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.testng</groupId>
<artifactId>testng</artifactId>
<version>6.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
<artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
<version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
<version>3.16</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
<version>3.16</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
<version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: What about run 'mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose'? Can you see 'commons-collections4' (- omitted for duplicate) or something similar? Paste your output from dependency:tree.

Comment: Are you executing this through a jar file or eclipse/any other IDE?

Comment: @Serio Gragera - [warning] The pom for org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.1 is invalid, transitive dependencies <if any> will not be available , enable debug logging  for more details

Comment: @KrishnaKuntala - Eclipse through maven dependencies

Comment: Try changing version to 4.0. Just to check.

Comment: @KrishnaKuntala: issue is with maven dependency , please do not use collection jar dependency, use external common collection jar file version 4.1

Comment: @KrishnaKuntala: is there any resolution for maven dependency of common-collections4.1 because in github not able to commit my project with the jar file however i have edited gitignore but not allowing to commit, i have to add maven dependency of this jar file

Comment: @NishantOmar what are you trying to achieve? Are you using any IDE? This dependency is available in central m2 repository. Please post your complete `pom.xml` so that we can help you out.

Comment: @KrishnaKuntala: I am using IDE, sure

Comment: which IDE you are using? Post complete pom.xml to understand the problem better.

Comment: @KrishnaKuntala: please check the post, i have posted complete pom.xml, IDE - neon.3 is using

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your **pom.xml** is; it is not assembling all the dependencies in your jar. Add maven assembly plugin to your **pom.xml**.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>{your.package.name.MainClass}</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Replace `{your.package.name.MainClass}` with your main class.

I have restructured your **pom.xml** to get this working. Please use below pom.xml to build your executable jar file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>practice</groupId>
    <artifactId>Practice_pblm</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Central Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Central Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>{your.package.name.MainClass}</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>3.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**P.S.** : Use **Practice_pblm.jar** (includes dependencies in a single file) for your execution instead of **Practice_pblm-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar** (does not include dependencies)

Comment: Krishna: but i do not have any main class, I using TestNG annotations then what should i mention in place of main class tag.

Comment: Remove manifest tag.. its added just in case you have main class.

Comment: Krishna: showing an error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDegfFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections4/ListValuedMap", i have changed my pom.xml and removed manifest tag. please help

Comment: now i am getting error"Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6" while execution please help.

Comment: Which jar file are you using for execution from target directory?

Comment: by mistaken i have deleted .m2 folder from my machine after that when i have updating my project then it is throwing an error, Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6 Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6"

Comment: Even if you have deleted the .m2 repository accidently, maven will create it automatically. From the error I could see that its failing to read one or more dependencies.

Comment: Just delete the `.m2/repository` directory and try again.

Comment: deleted and not able to update project in eclipse, same error is showing.

Comment: Thanks Krishna, i have tried in outside office network it is working fine, then updating is successful done now.